# Is it possible to listen with multiple port for multiple client in single JPOS instance?

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I am new in JPOS. We have implemented jpos server for multiple clients.

[here is a image of my scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CD0p.jpg)

For example, we have *n* number of clients. ISO message format are different for each client.

Is it possible to implement multiple listening port for each client in JPOS server?

If no, then what will be the best practice to process multiple client with single JPOS server instance?

How can we identify each client while processing ECHO and Sign-on request?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly add multiple q2 servers.

Just add another xml definition of a q2 server in your dist folder, jPOS would immediately pick up the new server and start listening to your specified port.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, why not, you can add as many servers as you want, with different protocols. Take a look at http://jpos.org/tutorials and just add more servers to your deploy directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group,selector, participant features of JPOS to process echo and request.

Sample code for Selector and Group

```
    <participant class="org.jpos.demo.group.Selector" name="Selector" logger="Q2">
            <property name="1100" value="Request" />
            <property name="1800" value="Echo" />
    </participant>

     <group name="Request">
            <participant class="org.jpos.demo.transaction.Request" logger="Q2" realm="prepare-response">
            </participant>
</group>

     <group name="Echo">
            <participant class="org.jpos.demo.transaction.Echo" logger="Q2" realm="prepare-echo">
            </participant>
         </group>
```

A selector can identify the MTI of incoming message example: 1100 for request and 1800 for echo.
The Selector class can implement GroupSelector and Configurable and overrides the below method to get MTI

```
@Override
        public String select(long l, Serializable serializable) {
            Context ctx = (Context)serializable;
            ISOMsg resIsoMsg = (ISOMsg)ctx.get(REQUEST);
            String selector = "";
            try {
                selector = configuration.get(resIsoMsg.getMTI());
            } catch (ISOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return selector;
        }
```